# Is $[G_p \cap G_q:G_{pq}]$ always finite? v2.0

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finitely-generated

Suppose $G$ is a finitely generated group. $G_n = \langle\{g^n| g \in G\}\rangle$. Suppose $p$ and $q$ are coprime integers. Is the index of $G_{pq}$ in $G_p \cap G_q$ always finite?

I have recently asked a similar question about arbitrary groups and received an infinitely generated counterexample: 
[Is $[G_p \cap G_q:G_{pq}]$ always finite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2811595/is-g-p-cap-g-qg-pq-always-finite)

However, the question, whether the statement is true under this additional condition, or is there a finitely generated counterexample, seems to be quite interesting and still remains unanswered.

Comment: Indeed, very good question; at the moment I don't know how to answer it

Comment: I answered your other question with what is partly an extended comment relevant to this question (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2812370/10513)).

Comment: I'd suggest posting this on MathOverflow. I wouldn't be surprised if one of the known Burnside groups (e.g. the Gupta-Sidki group) is a counterexample.